# canvas разбить круг на полигоны

Tags: javascript, canvas

Суть задачи такая, имеем круг нарисованный на canvas.
Нам нужно разбить Круг на полигоны, т.е мы задаем число сколько должно быть полигонов. Допустим 100 , значит круг делим на 100 частей,и так далее.

Решения в сети как странно не нашел, даже как примерно реализовать.

Мб подскажите ? или готовые уже библиотеки.

PS: Так же что бы с полигонами можно взаимодействовать, например кликнуть.

Ниже на рисунке я красным выделил примерно как должен делиться круг.Полигонов может быть разное число от 50 до 700 примерно
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. На какие 2 полигона должен разделиться круг?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, но на канвасе легко рисовать сектора. А вообще, тут даже метка [tag:javascript] не стоит. Я сначала хотел добавить, а потом передумал...

Comment: Думал что объяснил понятно, попробую еще раз.
Залил изображение выше.
Нарисовали круг. Нам нужно разделить на 4 части допустим.(это значит 4 полигона получить)
Мб это называется не полигонами, хотя занимался 3d моделированием и мне казалось это полигональная сетка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Вот в этом и вопрос, 4 полигона это только пример , что бы проще было, на самом деле разделить круг надо будет примерно на 50-700 полигонов(я буду называть это так)
И если мы будем рисовать их от центра 1й линией то 500шт просто напросто получится не юзабильно ,кликнуть будет сложно согласитесь.
Примерная полигональная сетка как должна выглядеть.
http://pichost.me/2040734/
Красными линиями начеркал

Comment: @MishaGubanov аааа. вот все таки что имеется в виду, просто из рисунка в вопросе и самого вопроса может показаться, что делим на равные сектора, а из вашего рисунка в комментарии уже стало понятно, что необходимо .... лучше его как раз поместить в вопрос и написать объяснение

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ага я понял вас так и сделаем